# How does DefinitelyTyped bind the declaration file to the JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm wondering how each declared type of `DefinitelyTyped` is bound to its related JavaScript library. e.g. How is `@type/lodash` linked to the js library `lodash`?

It's indicated by the manual that we can add a `"type"` tag in the `package.json` in the npm package, but I didn't see so after searching in several JavaScript components, including `angular`, `ace`,etc.

Could anyone proficient in TypeScript tell me the trick? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a default compiler option. In the tsconfig you can set a `typeRoots` property. By default it is set to `node_modules/@types` hence it will load all the type definitions which you have downloaded into the @types folder. You can also overwrite this setting (for example if you need to provide own typings additionally), therefore change this in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

The "types" property in the package.json is for npm packages where you can ship type definitions along with your library. This tells the typescript compiler where it can find the according type definitions. Many libraries don't ship these type definitions along with the npm package. For such packets you would need to download a type definitions from the Definetely Typed repo or create your own custom typing. Lodash is apparently one of these packages.

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to mark it as answer too, so that others know your question has been answered :-). Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: One issue. The `package.json` field is called `"types"` not `"type"`